# Grant permissions IIS 7 Microsoft windows server 2008

Tags: iis, permissions, sql-grant

I have a web service which I have deployed on IIS  7. No whenever a client calls web service method, then internal server error(500) is thrown back and we get
"The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security."
So i spent some time figuring out the reason for this error. 
Seems like if you do not have permission to EventLog registry entry, you wont be able to create events. 
You can go to registry key, right click on it and then Permissions. Assign ASPNET user required accesses. 
But i IIS 7, there is no user account as ASPNET. The application pool for my web site is under ApplicationPoolIdentity. So my question is how to grant permissions to ApplicationPoolIdentity account???
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For each Application Pool in IIS a user will be automatically created by the system.

For example, to the  will exist.

```
Application Pool           User Name
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ASP.NET v4.0            => [IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0]
ASP.NET v4.0 Integrated => [IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 Integrated]
DefaultAppPool          => [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
Classic .NET AppPool    => [IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool]
```

If the application pool is running under ApplicationPoolIdentity indentity, grant permission to this user and all will be fine!

Answer (score 0):

The ApplicationPoolIdentity user can be allocated permissions by searching for the username 
`IIS AppPool\websitename`.

For example, say the IIS website is hello.com, it would be `IIS AppPool\hello.com`.

HTH